# Is this the correct way to split video?

Tags: node.js

I am using the technique mentioned here to read a video file and split it and write it to a directory. But the problem is only first video is playable, the others can't be played.

```
fs.readFile('./assets/video.mp4', async function (err, data) {
if (err) {
    throw err;
}
//console.log(data);
var movie_data = data;

var i,
    j,
    temparray,
    chunk = 1000000,
    index = 0;
for (i = 0, j = movie_data.length; i < j; i += chunk, index++) {
    temparray = movie_data.slice(i, i + chunk);
    fs.writeFileSync(`./output/${index}.mp4`, temparray, 'binary');
}
```

})

Comment: what is the problem in the other generated videos? inspect them with ffmpeg to get a detailed metadata information of your wrong videos

Comment: When I am checking the properties, the frame rates, duration is not showing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No that is not the right way to split videos, since your player does need certain meta information (search the internet for `mp4 moov atom`, to explain everything is above this topic) to play that video correctly, and they are usually in the beginning of the file (since we want our mp4 to start playing while we download), and hence that is why only your first file works. They could be at the very end of the file as well, but as i said nowadays that not really any longer used.

You will need something like `ffmpeg` to correctly split your videos, since `ffmpeg` will write the correct meta data to where it is needed.